# node mysql returns undefined instead of the password

Tags: mysql, node.js

when i console.log user it returns the user, but when i console.log user.password it returns undefined. 
Is there another way to just get the password?

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'email@email.com'", function(err, user) {
 if (err) throw err;
 console.log(user)           //returns the user
 console.log(user.password); //returns undefined
});
```

Comment: what? i am sorry i dont understand

Comment: user.password It is well written

Comment: sorry, i not speak english

Comment: it is okay just try google translate or something

Comment: How does the `user` console log look like? Could you add that to your question?

Comment: I'm guessing `user` is actually an array or collection or some sort rather than a single user object. You probably need to iterate it or try `console.log(user[0].password)`.  I would expect the query to return an array of rows (even if only 1 row) rather than a single row object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **user[0].password** instead of **user.password**  and pass user email to statement and set limit to make it fast if you are retrieve one record.Suppose you pass email from form so **req.body.email**

```
connection.query('select * from users where user_email=? limit 1',[req.body.email],function (error,user,fields) {
    if(error) {
        res.send(error);
    } else {
        console.log("your email is "+user[0].user_email+ "and pass "+user[0].user_password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to check that user not equal null

```
if(!user){
   console.log('No Users');
}
```

then check the result if it's Array of objects or just single object
if it's single object your code should work just fine 
other wise you will need to loop through the elements

```
for(let el in user){
console.log(el); //This should print each user
}
```

or just access any element first you need to check that user you want by the Index

```
console.log(user[indexNumber].password);
```